# Docker nodejs server running in VirtualBox guest OS (Ubuntu Server 20.04): access via host (Win10) localhost

Tags: docker, localhost, virtualbox

I'm using docker inside VirtualBox (Ubuntu Server 20.04), since I cannot use Docker Desktop in the host (Windows 10).

I have a docker nodejs container on port 3000. In my host I can access it through `192.168.56.110:3000`, where 192.168.56.110 is the IP address of the VM but I need to access it through `localhost:3000`.

The setup is of course similar to a docker-toolbox installation (as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44218615/docker-machine-virtualbox-vm-export-container-port-to-host-machine-fail)), for which I've found that the host `localhost` also does not work, to put it simple.

I've tried to map localhost in Windows 10, as suggested in a few answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16639798/change-localhost-to-ip-with-port) adding to `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`:

```
192.168.56.110 localhost
192.168.56.110 dev.com
```

But while `dev.com` works right away as expected, `localhost` doesn't.

Is there a workaround?

When I run an Angular development server in the guest, I can access it via `localhost:4200` from the host but it is not completely clear to me what happens behind the scenes. Side question, how does `ng serve` lead to the "redirection" of `localhost` in the host OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run as administor a windows command prompt and enter:

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenaddress=127.0.0.1 listenport=3000 connectaddress=<replace with docker ip address> connectport=3000
```

To confirm, run

```
netsh interface portproxy show all
```

Good luck.

Comment: This works very well, thank you. The exact command to add the forwarding rule I needed:  `netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenaddress=127.0.0.1 listenport=3000 connectaddress=192.168.56.110 connectport=3000`. To remove the rule: `netsh interface portproxy delete v4tov4 listenport=3000 listenaddress=127.0.0.1`.